# Accessing the uri within the template_preprocess_image_formatter

Tags: 8, hooks

I am using template_preprocess_image_formatter and I am trying to access the uri protected property inside the URL array (see screenshot)

[image]

does anybody know how to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've sorted it

you can do it like this

```
$variables['url']->getUri()
```